# Where is the scroll for the second Ice Magic spell?

Tags: legend-of-grimrock

I found the 2nd Ice Magic spell through trial and error.  I'd like to wait until I find the scroll before I start using the spell.

I'm currently on level 6.

**Did I miss the scroll?  Which level can I find it on?**

*If the scroll exists, please spoiler the level and tell me outside the spoiler if I already missed it or not.*

It seems I'm already getting scrolls for higher point spells (much greater than 7 points in other skill ladders), so it feels like I must have missed it.

The scroll I'm looking for (spoilered):

> Spell: Enchant Frost Arrow

Comment: There is no particular reason to avoid using spells until you get the scroll. The manual lists what each rune does, and the spells follow the runic roles pretty well. In particular, if you've gotten fire arrow, it's well within reason to discover frost arrow on your own just by swapping the fire rune for the ice rune. I don't consider that cheesy at all.

Comment: @MyrddinEmrys: That's not an answer to the question, but it is useful to me to the point that I would accept it as one for now :)  I'm gonna try extracting the level files and see if I can figure it out tho, so I will add my own answer.  I'll reference your comment when I find out there is no such scroll.

Comment: Definitively a good question, I don't like to "cheat" and use the spell without finding the scroll first. Bounty here!

Comment: @Drake It isn't considered cheating. You're intended to experiment and the manual shows which runes do what. If 7 is fireburst then it's safe to assume that 9, 1, and 3 are simple nukes or spells from the other three elements.

Comment: I did some research too and it really seems the spell does not exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note: My answer contains minor spoilers for the runes necessary to cast fireburst (the very first spell scroll you find), fire shield, ice shield, and also the locations of the runes for the four elements (fire, ice, air, and earth).

There isn't a scroll for that spell. Seeing as you don't require the scroll of a spell to cast that spell, it's safe to assume you're intended to experiment with spell casting.

Think of it this way, the first spell scroll you find explains how to cast the basic fire spell, and thus you learn that the 7 rune (look at your numpad) is the fire rune. If you reach a point in your fire magic skill tree (we'll say 16) and you see that you've unlocked the ability to cast a new spell but you haven't found the scroll for it yet, you should definitely start experimenting by selecting the fire rune (7) and trying other runes in combination with it to see if you can discover what it is, because just like in this scenario there very well may not be a scroll for it. Just try different combinations: 7 and 8, 7 and 9, etc. Eventually you would come to the conclusion that 7 and 5 results in the fire shield spell and that you could just as easily make an ice shield with 3 and 5 instead because 3 is the ice rune (the four elements are in the corners).

If you need further confirmation that you are by no means cheating by doing this, think of it also from a lore perspective; wizards are scholarly, they're eager to gain more knowledge of their arts and they are no doubt constantly studying and experimenting with their spells, trying to learn new ones and to make their old ones better. You are without a doubt intended to experiment with your spells/runes this way, if you weren't the developers would have made it so that you also require the scroll of a spell in addendum to the necessary skill level to cast it.

Comment: For Enchant Ice Arrows specifically, you find the Enchant Poison Arrow scroll fairly early on.  Just follow it, but turn off the Earth Rune and turn on the Ice Rune.  Same applies for changing Fire Shield to Ice Shield but removing Fire instead.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there's no scroll for that spell.
I still have to find an official confirmation, but many sources on the internet seem to confirm this (examples [here](http://www.gog.com/en/forum/legend_of_grimrock/spellsscrolls) and [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/641157-legend-of-grimrock/62567763)).

Anyway the scrolls don't hold the actual spell, they just show you how to perform it, so there's no reason to hold on using it. You can guess the whole set of spells by trial and error and just use them, provided you're skilled enough.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, there doesn't appear to be one.

This is strange because the rollover text for the skills window specifically says you need the scroll to cast the spell (which is wrong in any case).